# Why doesn't my id shown in the page

Tags: php

I was doing the shopping cart tutorial, following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXqbQy9fOp8.
I followed the code closely, but couldn't get the same outcome.

my item id and quantity suppose to be shown when I click add to cart, however, only my quantity shown. Can someone tell me what's is wrong with my code?

Thanks
here is my coding..

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) || count($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["supermarketcart"] = array(1 => array("id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["supermarketcart"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["supermarketcart"], $i-1, 1, array(array("id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["supermarketcart"], array("id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }
    }
    header("location: cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php
//if user choose to empty cart
if(isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart")
{
    unset($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]);
}
?>

<?php
//render the cart for user to view
$cartOutput = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) || count($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) < 1 ){
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align = 'center'> Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
}
else
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["supermarketcart"] as $each_item)
    {
        $i++;
        $cartOutput = "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
        while(list($key,$value) = each($each_item))
        {
            $cartOutput ="$key:$value</br>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append    cartOutput in loop. you have re assigned cartOutput in each time.

**try like this:**

```
 $cartOutput = "";
    if(!isset($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) || count($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) < 1 ){
        $cartOutput .= "<h2 align = 'center'> Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
    }
    else
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["supermarketcart"] as $each_item)
        {
            $i++;
            $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
            while(list($key,$value) = each($each_item))
            {
                $cartOutput .="$key:$value</br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user3156220: did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$cartOutput = "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";

$cartOutput = "$key:$value</br>"
```

Problem is in these lines. You are rewriting the cartOutput variable at every step of the loop (thus clearing the 'id').
You should append the data instead:

```
$cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";

$cartOutput .= "$key:$value"
```